# Two-dimensional Ekman Spiral in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to plot Ekman spiral curve in 2-D figure (u-v plot)

I have the following equation:

```
z = rang from (-228,0)
u = V0*cos(alpha*z + 3*pi/4)*e^(alpha*z)
v = V0*sin(alpha*z + 3*pi/4)*e^(alpha*z)
V0 = 0.1314; alpha = 0.013738, Az = 0.1, f = 3.775e-05
```

How could I use these equation to plot this figure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from numpy import cos, sin, e, pi, linspace
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

z = linspace(-228,0,1000)
V0 = 0.1314
alpha = 0.013738
u = V0*cos(alpha*z + 3*pi/4)*e**(alpha*z)
v = V0*sin(alpha*z + 3*pi/4)*e**(alpha*z)

plt.plot(u,v)
plt.show()
```